# Python Augmented arithmetic in for loop range

Tags: python, loops, range

I've got assignment to multiply 256x2x2x2 by using loop in range using this code.

```
jawaban_5 = 256
for ... in range(...): # Use Range
    jawaban_5 ...= ... # Use Augmented Arithmetic 
    
print(jawaban_5)
```

with the result of 2048.

But everytime what i did is 0 using this code

```
jawaban_5 = 256
for x in range(2): # Tentukan range yang sesuai
    jawaban_5 *= x # Gunakan Augmented Arithmetic Assignments
    
print(jawaban_5)
```

Can someone explain to me how to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

`range` starts at 0, so it makes the result 0 in the first step.

You need to use the number 2 as multiplier, not the number from the range. Also, your range needs to be `3` as you multiply by `2` 3 times

```
jawaban_5 = 256
for x in range(3): # 3 loops
    jawaban_5 *= 2 
    
print(jawaban_5)
```

output: `2048`